# Discord.js Emoji Collector

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i have litle problem when i using collector i tried test with logging actions. Then where is problem when i remove/delete reaction from message its doesnt react i must add reaction first time and that removing/deleting reaction detect works after setting first time reaction but previously reaction doesnt works.

```
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector({ dispose: true });
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
   console.log("Collect");
});
collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
   console.log("remove");
});
```

Comment: Are you saying it's not detecting the message's reactions being removed, if it wasn't added after the collector was created?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, what's happening here is that the message in which the reactions are being added/removed is not cached by the bot on boot, and it is only cached after the first reaction gets added or removed from it, this is why the second action is detected but the first one isn't.

One away to solve this would be to cache the message on startup by fetching it using `<TextChannel>.messages.fetch(<MESSAGE_ID>)`.

Answer (score 0):

I find way how fix this

```
msg.createReactionCollector({ dispose: true });

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) =>
{
    console.log("ReactionAdded");
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) =>
{
    console.log("ReactionAdded");
});
```